# how i can insert image in header of word document by JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

By Using `jquery.wordexport.js` and `FileSaver.js` I am getting a word document created with given data , what i have to change in `jquery.wordexport.js` to get image in header of the word document.

Please suggest with code or links will be appreciated a lot.
Thanks in advance.

My `jquery.wordexport.js` looks as below

```
if (typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && typeof saveAs !== "undefined") {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.wordExport = function(fileName) {
            fileName = typeof fileName !== 'undefined' ? fileName : "jQuery-Word-Export";
            var static = {
                mhtml: {
                    top: "Mime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Base: " + location.href + "\nContent-Type: Multipart/related; boundary=\"NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\";type=\"text/html\"\n\n--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Location: " + location.href + "\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n_html_</html>",
                    head: "<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n<style>\n_styles_\n</style>\n</head>\n",
                    body: "<body>_body_</body>"
                }
            };
            var options = {
                maxWidth: 624
            };
            // Clone selected element before manipulating it
            var markup = $(this).clone();

            // Remove hidden elements from the output
            markup.each(function() {
                var self = $(this);
                if (self.is(':hidden'))
                    self.remove();
            });

            // Embed all images using Data URLs
            var images = Array();
            var img = markup.find('img');
            for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
                // Calculate dimensions of output image
                var w = Math.min(img[i].width, options.maxWidth);
                var h = img[i].height * (w / img[i].width);
                // Create canvas for converting image to data URL
                var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
                canvas.width = w;
                canvas.height = h;
                // Draw image to canvas
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0, w, h);
                // Get data URL encoding of image
                var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                $(img[i]).attr("src", img[i].src);
                img[i].width = w;
                img[i].height = h;
                // Save encoded image to array
                images[i] = {
                    type: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(":") + 1, uri.indexOf(";")),
                    encoding: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(";") + 1, uri.indexOf(",")),
                    location: $(img[i]).attr("src"),
                    data: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(",") + 1)
                };
            }

            // Prepare bottom of mhtml file with image data
            var mhtmlBottom = "\n";
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                mhtmlBottom += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\n";
                mhtmlBottom += "Content-Location: " + images[i].location + "\n";
                mhtmlBottom += "Content-Type: " + images[i].type + "\n";
                mhtmlBottom += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " + images[i].encoding + "\n\n";
                mhtmlBottom += images[i].data + "\n\n";
            }
            mhtmlBottom += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY--";

            //TODO: load css from included stylesheet
            var styles = "";

            // Aggregate parts of the file together
            var fileContent = static.mhtml.top.replace("_html_", static.mhtml.head.replace("_styles_", styles) + static.mhtml.body.replace("_body_", markup.html())) + mhtmlBottom;

            // Create a Blob with the file contents
            var blob = new Blob([fileContent], {
                type: "application/msword;charset=utf-8"
            });
            saveAs(blob, fileName + ".doc");
        };
    })(jQuery);
} else {
    if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
        console.error("jQuery Word Export: missing dependency (jQuery)");
    }
    if (typeof saveAs === "undefined") {
        console.error("jQuery Word Export: missing dependency (FileSaver.js)");
    }
}
```

My FileSaver.js is as below

```
/*! @source http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js */
   var saveAs=saveAs||function(e){"use strict";if("undefined"==typeof navigator||!/MSIE [1-9]\./.test(navigator.userAgent)){var t=e.document,n=function(){return e.URL||e.webkitURL||e},o=t.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","a"),r="download"in o,i=function(e){var t=new MouseEvent("click");e.dispatchEvent(t)},a=/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent),c=e.webkitRequestFileSystem,d=e.requestFileSystem||c||e.mozRequestFileSystem,u=function(t){(e.setImmediate||e.setTimeout)(function(){throw t},0)},s="application/octet-stream",f=0,l=4e4,v=function(e){var t=function(){"string"==typeof e?n().revokeObjectURL(e):e.remove()};setTimeout(t,l)},p=function(e,t,n){t=[].concat(t);for(var o=t.length;o--;){var r=e["on"+t[o]];if("function"==typeof r)try{r.call(e,n||e)}catch(i){u(i)}}},w=function(e){return/^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(e.type)?new Blob(["\uFEFF",e],{type:e.type}):e},y=function(t,u,l){l||(t=w(t));var y,m,S,h=this,R=t.type,O=!1,g=function(){p(h,"writestart progress write writeend".split(" "))},b=function(){if(m&&a&&"undefined"!=typeof FileReader){var o=new FileReader;return o.onloadend=function(){var e=o.result;m.location.href="data:attachment/file"+e.slice(e.search(/[,;]/)),h.readyState=h.DONE,g()},o.readAsDataURL(t),void(h.readyState=h.INIT)}if((O||!y)&&(y=n().createObjectURL(t)),m)m.location.href=y;else{var r=e.open(y,"_blank");void 0===r&&a&&(e.location.href=y)}h.readyState=h.DONE,g(),v(y)},E=function(e){return function(){return h.readyState!==h.DONE?e.apply(this,arguments):void 0}},N={create:!0,exclusive:!1};return h.readyState=h.INIT,u||(u="download"),r?(y=n().createObjectURL(t),void setTimeout(function(){o.href=y,o.download=u,i(o),g(),v(y),h.readyState=h.DONE})):(e.chrome&&R&&R!==s&&(S=t.slice||t.webkitSlice,t=S.call(t,0,t.size,s),O=!0),c&&"download"!==u&&(u+=".download"),(R===s||c)&&(m=e),d?(f+=t.size,void d(e.TEMPORARY,f,E(function(e){e.root.getDirectory("saved",N,E(function(e){var n=function(){e.getFile(u,N,E(function(e){e.createWriter(E(function(n){n.onwriteend=function(t){m.location.href=e.toURL(),h.readyState=h.DONE,p(h,"writeend",t),v(e)},n.onerror=function(){var e=n.error;e.code!==e.ABORT_ERR&&b()},"writestart progress write abort".split(" ").forEach(function(e){n["on"+e]=h["on"+e]}),n.write(t),h.abort=function(){n.abort(),h.readyState=h.DONE},h.readyState=h.WRITING}),b)}),b)};e.getFile(u,{create:!1},E(function(e){e.remove(),n()}),E(function(e){e.code===e.NOT_FOUND_ERR?n():b()}))}),b)}),b)):void b())},m=y.prototype,S=function(e,t,n){return new y(e,t,n)};return"undefined"!=typeof navigator&&navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob?function(e,t,n){return n||(e=w(e)),navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(e,t||"download")}:(m.abort=function(){var e=this;e.readyState=e.DONE,p(e,"abort")},m.readyState=m.INIT=0,m.WRITING=1,m.DONE=2,m.error=m.onwritestart=m.onprogress=m.onwrite=m.onabort=m.onerror=m.onwriteend=null,S)}}("undefined"!=typeof self&&self||"undefined"!=typeof window&&window||this.content);"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports.saveAs=saveAs:"undefined"!=typeof define&&null!==define&&null!==define.amd&&define([],function(){return saveAs});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wordexport.js` takes advantage of Word's ability to render HTML content in a `.doc` file. So the answer is the same as if you were adding an image to an HTML document: the [`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) tag:

```
...
var static = {
    mhtml: {
        top: "Mime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Base: " + location.href + "\nContent-Type: Multipart/related; boundary=\"NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\";type=\"text/html\"\n\n--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Location: " + location.href + "\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n_html_</html>",
        head: "<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n<style>\n_styles_\n</style>\n</head>\n",
        body: "<body><img src="http://www.example.com/media/examples/frog.png" alt="Frog"/>_body_</body>"
    }
};
...
```

According to [this page](http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=word_document_generation), setting the `mso-element` style appropriately can be used to specify headers and footers. Without fully trying it out, you may also have to treat the header/footer as a separate file (which gets combined in the 'Aggregate parts of the file together' part):

```
<div style="mso-element:header;" id="h1">
  <img src="http://www.example.com/media/examples/frog.png" alt="Frog"/>
</div>

<div style='mso-element:footer' id=f1>
  <img src="http://www.example.com/media/examples/frog.png" alt="Frog"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for response but with your given code i can get image in body of the word document , i want this image  in header section of the word document  , please suggest sir

Comment: Sir i could not customize the code available in your given link ( this page ) , Can you please help me with sharing a example of inserting image in header of word document in the initial attached Code scenario. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Or Can we use a existing word document to store the data here so that in existing document we can put header image manually , is this is possible sir , please suggest ,  thanks and regards.